# Aligning text for a WPF button with multiple elements

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a button with multiple content lines which I would like to align differently, but I can not get it to work.

I have tried using a StackPanel, DockPanel and grid, but same result.

Here is an attempt using a grid:

```
  <Button>
    <Button.Content >
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20" ></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" ></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock  Text="Left" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <TextBlock  Text="Middle" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  />
            </Grid>
        </Button.Content>
    </Button>
```

There is an older thread, [WPF Button with multiple text elements for 10 foot gui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18605624/wpf-button-with-multiple-text-elements-for-10-foot-gui), but I can not get that to work even though it is set to solved.
Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Ensure that outer `Grid` column/`Button` width is more than the width of the inner control. `Auto` column width is minimal to contain the control. E.g. you're trying to align control with 30px width in a grid column with 30px width.

Comment: Can you please describe what layout you want and what you are getting instead?

Comment: Note that the `Button` aligns its content centered by default

Comment: 20px is not very wide at all. I'm also a bit confused by "multiple content lines". You only have the one row, so i would describe the two textblocks as being on the same line.  Should these really be rowdefinitions rather than columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what result you are actually getting. But the alignment won't behave as you expect (I guess), since the content of the `Button` is centered by default. To utilize the full content area you must allow the content to stretch horizontally, and if required vertically too:

```
<Button HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" />
```

Next thing I realize is that you are using a  column width of `Auto`. You should know that `TextBlock` will measure itself to occupy the least available space - minimal size. Setting the column width to `Auto` will result in a column where the width equals the width of the `TextBlock`: `TextBlock.HorizontalAlignment="Center"` won't have any effect, since there is no space to center anything. Solution is to set the column width (at least of the column that contains an element which requests centered alignment) to `*`. `*` will force the column to occupy the remaining avaible space:

```
<Button HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
  <Button.Content>
    <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

      <TextBlock Text="Left" Grid.Column="0" />
      <TextBlock Text="Middle" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
  </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved my issue:

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                <ContentPresenter />
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Text="Left" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Text="Middle" />
    </Grid>
</Button>
```